# Mac OS X Read XML File Into Text Fields

Tags: objective-c, xml, macos

I have an xml file stored on my website that looks like this:

```
<games>
<game id="12345">
    <title>Entropy</title>
    <creator>Ashley Staggs</creator>
</game>
</games>
```

How would I read this into 3 NSTextFields? All the things iv'e tried seem to only work on iPhone.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at NSXMLDocument. It's not on iOS, but on the Mac, it's a really easy way to parse out an XML file.